# Impromtu plug in is not working

Tags: jquery, plugins, impromptu

I like to have a popup modal dialog that need to show the list of options (like a radio button select event). But I don't know what I am missing! It works fine when no HTML tag is embedded in Impromtu. Do I include it in CSS?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="examples.css" TITLE="Contemporary" TYPE="text/css">
        <script src="jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="impromptu.1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){                
               $.prompt( '<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>',{ opacity: 0.2 });                
            });            
        </script>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this, no radio button is shown in the popup dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have told Impromtu is to show a message "Milk" inside the popup. You have not given it any radio button markup to show.

What you would need is  something like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $.prompt( '<input type="radio" value="1">Milk</input>',{ opacity: 0.2 }); 
});
```